# C# - Retrieve Group members of Active Directory using LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a group "My Group" in my Active Directory, i would like to retrieve the users from this group using Active Directory LDAP.

How do i modify my query to include Group and get the members from it ?

```
string username = “ldapuser”;
string password = “prime812”;
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(“LDAP://AM-LDAP-SN.ams.com/389/CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=AMS,dc=com”, username,password);
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

forreach(SearchResult sResultSet in deSearch.FindAll())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PrincipalContext isntead:

```
private static List<Principal> GetUsersOfGroup(string groupname)
{
    string username = "ldapuser";
    string password = "prime812";

    using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContentType.Domain, null, username, password))
    {
        var _users = new List<Principal>();
        var _group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupname);

        foreach(var member in group.GetMembers())
        {
            if(member is UserPrincipal _user)
                _users.Add(_user);
        }

        return _users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Working but it is taking 1 second to print each user, I have almost thousands of users.. any clue on why it is that slow ?

Comment: the principal objects could be slowing it down, try returning a list of just the info you need instead the object. I would do something like `return _users.Select(o => new { o.SamAccountName, o.DisplayName }).ToList();`